# Getting Null Pointer Exception in Twitter API consumption in .net

Tags: c#, twitter

I am developing a .net based application to consume Twitter API.I am getting the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

Code is as follows

```
StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml");
try
{
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("user"))
    {
        strB.Append("z: " + reader.GetAttribute("id").ToString());
        strB.Append(" | Y: " + reader.GetAttribute("name").ToString());
        strB.Append(" | style: " + reader.GetAttribute("style").ToString());
     }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
     Response.Write(ex.ToString()); 
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();
}
Response.Write(strB.ToString());
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance
Daman

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Comment: Where are you getting your NullReferenceException?

Comment: Verify that your reader is able to get hold of an id, name, and style. Place the results of calling `reader.GetAttribute("xxx")` into a variable, and look at the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name`, `id`, and `style` are *tags*, not attributes.
Therefore, `GetAttribute` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you given a thought about using a third party client library ?

Here are some of the free alternatives

- [tweetsharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [linq to twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Is there any free tool available?